# Php when to use final class

Tags: php

I want to know when I should mark my class as final ?

And if not can I extend a final class?

I'm using a ipinfodb api and its a final class that I want to use in my regular class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead of inheritance. The entire singular purpose of `final` classes is that you're not meant to inherit from them. You need to make a class which simply uses an instance of the `final` class internally.

Answer (score 0):

you can't extend final class. Extend means inheritance.
What means "include a final class in my class"?

You can make your own class, and then into that class create a member of your final class `var m_yourFinalClassObj = new MyFinalClass;`

Or just declare it:

```
     class MyClass
     {
        var m_yourFinalClassObj;
        ...
```

... and in the constructor go and initialize it (create the object of the final class)

Answer (score 0):

Final class is nothing more than a final class. It means, you just can't create a child class of a final class(No inheritance supported). You also can't override its' methods. But you actually can include it and use it in other classes.

Comment: That's the problem I'm including it into my class and it keeps saying that it can't find my class even though I've checked it over and over again.

Comment: Let me see your code. I need to see those 2 classes and how they are positioned in a project tree.

Answer (score 0):

the final class is same as sealed class in c# which means it is sealed it is further more cant inherited with other class however use this class by making its object in another class.